# Function to update WordPress custom post Metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

This issue has been raised a few times on here but from the countless posts I've researched I haven't been successful in finding a solution.

The site I'm working with is a coupon site and I have two custom posts, one for stores and another for coupons.

There is a relationship between the two, the stores custom post ID is imputed in a custom post meta 'offer_store' in the coupons custom post.

The issue I have is when I'm importing coupons through WP All Import the data is there, you can see this in the post admin edit page but the relationship isn't being matched unless I manually update the post inside the post admin edit page.

I import 1000s and can't do this manually so have been searching for a function.
There is a function you can use to run after an import is done:

```
add_action('pmxi_after_xml_import', 'after_xml_import', 10, 1);

function after_xml_import($import_id) {
    $import = (int) $import_id;
    if ( $import == 38 ) {

    }
}
```

Inside here I have tried `wp_update_post();`, `update_post_meta();`

Examples of code I've tried.

The below code updates the content but not the entire post or more specifically the custom post meta:

```
add_action('pmxi_after_xml_import', 'after_xml_import', 10, 1);

function after_xml_import($import_id) {
    $import = (int) $import_id;
    if ( $import == 38 ) {
        $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'offer', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
        foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):
            $my_post['post_content'] = ' offer';
            wp_update_post( $my_post );
        endforeach; 
    }
}
```

I think I've gotten the below code wrong, I'm trying to update the posts custom meta key (offer_store) with the same value the import imported:

```
add_action('pmxi_after_xml_import', 'after_xml_import', 10, 1);

function after_xml_import($import_id) {
    $import = (int) $import_id;
    if ( $import == 38 ) {
        $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'offer', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
        foreach ($my_posts as $my_post) {
            $offer_store_id = get_post_meta( $my_post->ID, 'offer_store', true );
            update_post_meta($my_post->ID, 'offer_store', $offer_store_id);
        }       
    }
}
```

I don't need any data to be changed, I just need a function that simulates the 'update' button.

I've searched the internet for a solution but cannot find one and am hoping someone on here can save my life.

Comment: I think this is the wrong way. After import the post IDs probably changed, so you should not assign the coupons the the store post id. Use a unique store identifer instead.

Comment: The stores post id doesn't ever change. Nothing in the stores post gets changed during the import, only the coupons post type. It's definitely the right ID because it says the store name in the back end, it's the front end this relationship isn't matching. When you manually update the post it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue I have is when I'm importing coupons through WP All Import the data is there, you can see this in the post admin edit page but the relationship isn't being matched unless I manually update the post inside the post admin edit page.

This is likely a problem of how you imported the data. I remember having the same issue with WP All Import, while importing into fields provided by ACF.

When importing into custom fields, you need to have *two* rows for each field in the WPAI Custom Fields section. One needs to be `fieldname` and `value`, and the other needs to be `_fieldname` (note the underscore) and `field_xyz`, the latter being the field identifier used by ACF.

Here is an example image of an import I used, you can see what I mean there:

[image: Screenshot of WP All Import configuration]

If you provide one row with fieldname and value only, then something is missing in the WP metadata table. Saving the post again through the UI fixes that, as you already discovered. You can avoid having to do that, when you provide the field data as described above.

---

WP All Import offers an additional plugin, specifically to deal with custom fields - that offers a drag&drop kind of interface, that creates these field combinations automatically. You do not necessarily need to use that, you can configure it all manually as shown above as well.

Comment: I see what you mean, I use ACF for some of my own custom meta but the imported data get's imported into custom meta fields created within the theme. I've looked in the postmeta table and unlike ACF meta fields, the fields created by the theme don't have a corresponding '_offer_store' and 'field_xyz'. Any ideas?

Comment: Might still be something similar. Could you check what entries the postmeta table contains for a specific post after your import, and if/how that changes after you just saved the post again via the UI?

Comment: Comparing the meta data after import and comparing with after manual update through UI identified some required meta data I missed off during the import. Silly mistake, but sometimes helps to talk the issue through with someone, thank you very much, wouldn't have gotten there without you. Cheers bud